# Suspected pyparsing longest match error

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I am developing a parser for the DOT language and am having problems with "subgraph" statements.

I have no problems getting my SUBGRAPH parse expression working correctly (see fragment below) however when I add it as an alternative in STMT it fails to match.

**Simple test:**

```
test = '''subgraph cluster01 { n003 ; n004 ;  }'''
FRAG_1 = SUBGRAPH + StringEnd()
FRAG_2 = STMT + StringEnd()

res1 = FRAG_1.parseString(test)  # OK
res2 = FRAG_2.parseString(test)  # ParseException -
```

**Error:**

```
subgraph cluster01 { n003 ; n004 ;  }
         ^
ERROR: Expected end of text (at char 9), (line:1, col:10)
```

I *suspect* the problem involves my STMT expression - that it greedy matches the keyword "subgraph" as a NODE_STMT rather than matching as a SUBGRAPH however my expectation is that by using an "Or" expression ("^") the longest match algorithm will choose SUBGRAPH over NODE_STMT. Or it could be something else.

My partial grammar is below:

**Grammar Fragment:**

```
LCURL = Literal("{").suppress()
RCURL = Literal("}").suppress()
STMTSEP = Literal(";").suppress()
ID = Word(alphas, alphanums + "_")
SUBGRAPH_KW = Keyword("subgraph", caseless=True)
SUBGRAPH = Forward("SUBGRAPH")

NODE_ID = ID("NODE_ID")
NODE_STMT = NODE_ID("NODE")

STMT = NODE_STMT("NODE") ^ SUBGRAPH("SUBGRAPH")
STMT_LIST = ZeroOrMore(STMT("STMT") + Optional(STMTSEP))

SUBGRAPH << Group(SUBGRAPH_KW + ID("SUBGRAPHNAME")) + Group(LCURL +    STMT_LIST + RCURL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're creating a *copy* of the `SUBGRAPH` object in this line:

```
STMT = NODE_STMT("NODE") ^ SUBGRAPH("SUBGRAPH")
```

Calling `setResultsName()`, which the call syntax is a shortcut for, [creates a copy of the ParserElement object](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.ParserElement-class.html#setResultsName).

This is a problem because `SUBGRAPH` is a `Forward` object, and at that point in the code it hasn't been fully defined yet.

You really shouldn't be setting names for everything, everywhere, all of the time! Do so when and where actually needed, and keep in mind that it creates copies of the `ParserElement` objects.

Comment: Brilliant! I will need to think about what the proper use of ParserElement.setResultName() actually is though...

Comment: Good catch! I've not seen this particular issue crop up in this particular form before (results name + Forward), definitely need to add to my list of pyparsing gotchas.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I recommend holding off on assigning results names until expressions are being assembled into a higher-level expression, like this:

```
intnum = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda t: int(t[0]))
realnum = Combine(Word(nums) + '.' + Word(nums)).setParseAction(lambda t: float(t[0]))
hostname = Word(alphas, alphanums+'-')
timestamp = Regex(r'\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d')
statslogentry = (timestamp('timestamp') + hostname('hostname') + 
                 'CPU:' + realnum('cpu') + 
                 'DISK_IO:' + intnum('disk_io') + 
                 'NETWORK_IO:' + intnum('network_io'))
```

However, when using `Forward` this can work against you, as is the case here. One specific error in the OP's code is

```
SUBGRAPH = Forward("SUBGRAPH")
```

I think the OP is trying to use the results name shortcut, but is actually creating a `Forward` with a content of `Literal("SUBGRAPH")`. Changing this to

```
SUBGRAPH = Forward()("SUBGRAPH")
```

and removing the results name from the `Or` expression would resolve the original problem. But I still think this falls somewhat into the "gotcha" category.

Comment: Thanks Paul. This is good advice. Also, many thanks for a great tool...